# Tricky Active Record search. Record created between 3 am and beginning_of day

Tags: ubuntu, activerecord, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ruby-on-rails-6, postgresql-10

I have a application to track temperatures as related to global warming.

I have a PG database recording temperatures and then trying to compare records created at beginning_of_day until 3 am or beginning_of_day+180.

@today_records = Temp.where(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day+180) 
works perfectly. However I need these records for days that are not Date.current or Time.zone.now or Time.zone.yesterday. These need to be the day the record was made which happens to be stored in created_at AND the date: column in the table.

I have tried things like @temps = Temp.all then @temps.where("created_at <= beginnig_of_day+180 AND created_at > beginning_of_day"). Something like this pseudocode would work if I could get the syntax and or order/placement correct.

The table has columns date, temp_high and I was trying to get the records created very early in the morning.   I know that an instance of Temp such as @temp.created_at.beginning_of_day+180 will be 3 am if that record was created at beginning_of_day exactly.

How can I use this is the search?

My models are city and temp where cities have many temps and temp belongs to a city

```
class City < ApplicationRecord 
    has_many :temps
end 

class Temp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
end 

create_table "temps", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "date"
    t.integer "temp_high"
    t.integer "temp_mid"
    t.integer "temp_low"
    t.bigint "city_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "sunset"
    t.index ["city_id"], name: "index_temps_on_city_id"
  end 
#routes.rb
get "/cities/temps/diff.json", to: 'temps#diff' 
#temps_controller 
 def diff 

      @cities = City.all 
      @temps = @cities.map{ |city| city.temps }  

      @hot = @temps.map{ |temp|  temp.map{ |city_temp| city_temp.try(:temp_high) } }   
      @cool = @temps.map{ |temp| temp.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3) } 
      render json: {HOTTEST: @hot, COOLEST: @cool }
    end
```

**update** The below response was in fact a good answer. In the application I get exactly what I am asking for: records created between 0000 and 3 am. **HOWEVER**

This query needs to be dynamic and change with a provided day. For example every day there query will take new data and do a calculation. This gives a really good answer but it is very static.

Can a date variable be injected into the query as well? I am no sql master and just finished learning rails.

`#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Temp id: 5, date: "2020-03-28 09:04:23", temp_high: 42, temp_mid: 35, temp_low: 28, city_id: 3, created_at: "2020-03-28 09:04:24", updated_at: "2020-03-28 09:04:24", sunset: 1585436723, current_temp: 35, sunset_datetime: "2020-03-28 23:05:23">]>                                                                                   2.6.1 :007 > x[0].created_at                                                                                              Temp Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "temps".* FROM "temps" WHERE "temps"."id" = $1  [["id", 5]]                                  => Sat, 28 Mar 2020 02:04:24 MST -07:00`

When you work with the record directly and pull it out of the database and ask it when it was created it gives you to correct time of 02:04:24

I have to set the timezone in postgresql. Postgesql is working on UTC and rails will convert this once it gets drawn out of the DB.

I am letting rails convert them and then doing the calculation afterwards once pulled out of the db. This is fine but I am basically working around the issue and doing less direct and more complex comparison between records and then doing math on the records including difference and rate(difference/time).

**update 2**

This code works really well to do what I originally wanted. I have not solved the problem of pulling the records for a specific day. This works for the current day only

```
    @afternoon = Temp.where("created_at BETWEEN 
           date_trunc('day', created_at) + interval '11 hour'  AND 
           date_trunc('day', created_at) + interval '17 hour' ").first(5);   

     @overnight = Temp.where("created_at BETWEEN 
           date_trunc('day', created_at) + interval '0 hour'  AND 
           date_trunc('day', created_at) + interval '5 hour' ").first(5);
```

This Post is for educational purposes for others.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work ok.

```
Temp.where("created_at BETWEEN 
            date_trunc('day', created_at) + interval '1 day' - interval '24 hour' AND 
            date_trunc('day', created_at) + interval '1 day' - interval '21 hour' ")
```

If the between doesn't work for you, you could play around with the `>=` and `<` operators.

Comment: This is good enough to play with and I would just move this as the answer. the POSTGRESQL query in the ActiveRecord search is a nice touch. Right now I'm playing around with why my active record is putting a created_at timestamp for a different time than it actually was. Time zones and discerning what is happening under the hood is the nature of the work:) BigThanks

Comment: Ya I hate dealing with timezones and such. I forget where but you can set the timezeon to UTC somewhere I think. I forget exactly how to handle that though :(